# What would be the limit

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

What would be the limit of:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1^2+3^2+...+(2n-1)^2}{2^2+4^2+...+(2n)^2}$$

Knowing that $2n-1$ is an arithmetic sequence the sum of it would be $\frac{n(a_{1}+a_{n})}{2}$, same goes as for $2n$

Using this fact i am able to evaluate it, $$\lim_{N \to \infty}\frac{\sum_{n=1}^{N}(2n-1)^2}{\sum_{n=1}^{N}(2n)^2}=1$$
Is this the general idea i should be going with, will it work for similar series, or is there any other way to solve it.

Comment: the sums in the numerator and denominator are not from $1$ to $\infty$-they should be from $1$ to $n$, and the summand should be over $k$.

Comment: also it's not the square of the sum-it's the sum of squares.

Comment: Yeah corrected it!

Comment: In limits like this Cesaro-Stolz is the best idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct way to evaluate this limit is to recall that $$\sum_{k=1}^n k^2 = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6},$$ hence the numerator is $$\begin{align*} \sum_{k=1}^n (2k-1)^2 &= \sum_{k=1}^n (2k-1)^2 + (2k)^2 - \sum_{k=1}^n (2k)^2 \\ &= \sum_{k=1}^{2n} k^2 - \sum_{k=1}^n 4k^2 \\ &= \sum_{k=1}^{2n} k^2 - 4 \sum_{k=1}^n k^2 \\ &= \frac{2n(2n+1)(4n+1)}{6} - 4 \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}. \end{align*}$$  But notice the denominator is the second term of the above expression, so we can get $$\frac{n(2n+1)(4n+1)}{2n(n+1)(2n+1)} - 1 = \frac{4n+1}{2(n+1)} - 1,$$ the limit of which as $n \to \infty$ is simply $1$.

Comment: Could you please explain this part $\sum_{k=1}^n (2k-1)^2 = \sum_{k=1}^{2n} k^2 - 4 \sum_{k=1}^n k^2$, how you got these series from the first one

Comment: $$\begin{align*} 1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2 + \cdots + (2n)^2 &= (1^2 + 3^2 + \cdots + (2n-1)^2) + (2^2 + 4^2 + \cdots + (2n)^2) \\ &= \sum_{k=1}^n (2k-1)^2 + \sum_{k=1}^n (2k)^2. \end{align*}$$  Then factor out the 4 from the second sum.

Comment: Think about it.  The sum of the first $2n$ squares can be rearranged into the sum of the even squares and the odd squares.  The even squares can have a factor of $4$ pulled out.  Then rearrange the resulting identity, so that you can express the sum of the odd squares in terms of the sum of the first $2n$ squares minus the sum of the first $n$ even squares.  I can't possibly make it any simpler than that.

Comment: Ok i think i got it now, the sequence $(2n-1)^2$ represents only odd numbers, and I ll have to write the sequence which represents all $(2n)^2$ numbers including the odd ones, then I ll have to subtract all even numbers from it to make it equivalent, or exactly as u mathematically wrote it! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

We have

$\displaystyle \begin{aligned}\dfrac{{\displaystyle \sum_{k = 1}^{n}(2k - 1)^{2}}}{{\displaystyle \sum_{k = 1}^{n}(2k)^{2}}} &= \dfrac{{\displaystyle \sum_{k = 1}^{n}(2k - 1)^{2}}}{{\displaystyle \sum_{k = 1}^{n}(2k)^{2}}} + 1 - 1\\
&= \dfrac{{\displaystyle \sum_{k = 1}^{2n}k^{2}}}{{\displaystyle \sum_{k = 1}^{n}(2k)^{2}}} - 1\\
&= \dfrac{\dfrac{2n(2n + 1)(4n + 1)}{6}}{\dfrac{4n(n + 1)(2n + 1)}{6}} - 1\\
&= \frac{4n + 1}{2(n + 1)} - 1\\
&= \dfrac{4 + \dfrac{1}{n}}{2\left(1 + \dfrac{1}{n}\right)} - 1\\
&\to 2 - 1 = 1 \text{ as }n \to \infty\end{aligned}$

Answer (score 1):

Use the fact that $\sum_{k=1}^{n}k=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ and $\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^2=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$. This simplifies things.

Comment: The expression should be $n(n+1)(2n+1)/6$, not $n(n+2)(2n+1)/6$, but I was unable to make a single-character edit.